# What is the source of my 'Execution Context Destroyed' error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am creating a program to scrape forum responses for the online Uni I work for. I managed to successfully navigate to the appropriate pages, but when I tried to include scraping for the list of names of the learners who have responded I receive an 'Execution context was destroyed error'.

So far I tried moving around page.waitFor() methods with varying amounts of timeouts.

```
   const nameLinkList = await page.$$eval(
            '.coursename',
            (courseLinks => courseLinks.map(link => {
                const a = link.querySelector('.coursename > a');
                return {
                    name: a.innerText,
                    link: a.href
                };
            }))
        );

        for (const {
                name,
                link
            } of nameLinkList) {
            await Promise.all([
                page.waitForNavigation(),
                page.goto(link),
                page.waitFor(2000),
            ]);

            let [button] = await page.$x("//a[contains(., 'Self')]");
            if (button) {
                await button.click();
            } else {
                console.log(name);
                console.log('Didnt find link');
            }

            fs.appendFile('out.csv', name + '\n');
            await page.waitFor(1000);
            var elementExists = await page.$$('.author .media-body');

            if (elementExists) {
                await console.log(name);
                await page.waitFor(500);
                for (let z of elementExists) {
                    const studentName = await z.$eval('a', a => a.innerText);
                    await page.waitFor(2000)
                    await console.log(studentName);
                }
            }
            await page.goto('www.urlwiththelistofcourses.com');

        }
```

I expected it to iterate through each page, logging first the name of the course, followed by the names of any students who posted on the courses particular forum. The thing that confuses me is that unlike previous errors which got stuck on a particular iteration this one is variable, usually in the same area, around the 12-17th iteration, sometimes even earlier.

Comment: I just started using node.js and puppeteer a couple days ago, so I welcome any feedback if you notice the above code doesn't reflect an understanding of how a certain method works or is intended to use. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a combination of adjusting the waitFor here:

```
 fs.appendFile('out.csv', name + '\n');
            await page.waitFor(1000);
            var elementExists = await page.$$('.author .media-body');
```

to 2000, combined with disabling the rendering of css and images solved the problem. The program must have linked away before entering the loop if the page loaded too slowly.

Comment: To ensure your tests work every time, you should use `page.waitForSelector(".author")`. It's also faster.

Comment: Also, your Q&A helped me figure out my own issue. I had navigated to another page and used `waitForResponse`. I expected the page to be fully loaded with the successful response, but it gave me the ECD error. It wasn't loaded, because when I waited for the selector, my error vanished and the code worked.